# Jquery Datables sorting_asc and sorting_desc not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

Jquery Datables **sorting_asc** and **sorting_desc** are not working after me  apply drag drop in the rows.

someone can help me on this issue I have 
jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/9/

html:

```
<div class=" dashboard">
  <div class="col-md-8 no-padding">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option value="Filter by">Filter by country </option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="EUA">EUA</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Place</th>
         <th>Order</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex){
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    },
    rowReorder: {
       dataSrc: 'order',
    },
    columns: [
      {
         data: 'order'
      },{
         data: 'name'
      },{
         data: 'place'
    }]
  });
    table.rowReordering();  


  $('#sel1').change(function() {
    if (this.value === "All") {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search('')
        .draw();
    } else {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Unofficial old [row reordering plugin](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/) forces sorting to be done only on the indexing column.

#### SOLUTION

Replace it with official [RowReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder) extension that doesn't have that limitation, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/simple.html).

Remove `table.rowReordering();` and include additional files files for RowReorder plugin.

Also RowReorder plug-in requires jQuery DataTables 1.10.8 or newer.

#### EXAMPLE

See [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/13/) for code and demonstration.